# Write the content of sql row into varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Does anybody know how can I fill in the varchar variable with the content of any row in T-SQL table ?

For example, I have next table:

```
id   name   Age  city
1    Alice  10   London
```

When we read the current value of column we need to check if it is NOT NULL we write it to the @description variable.

I need to get the result in a next maner:

```
@description = "id: 1; name: Alice; Age: 10; city: London";
```

I will be very glad if someone could tell me how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but WTF is a cortege?

Comment: sorry, it`s mean 1 row in sql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the columns (you'll have to convert the numeric columns first):

```
select 
  'id: ' + convert(varchar(10), id) + '; name: ' + name + 
  '; Age: ' + convert(varchar(10), age) + '; city: ' + city 
from test
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03817/7)